# Ember best practice: Mixin vs Component

Tags: ember.js, components, mixins

I have component B that extends from component A, also I have component D that extends from component C. Between B and D there is some share code to upload to s3 but they actually aren't much related.
Still I don't like the code duplication but I don't know if I should:

1. Write a mixin and import in both components.
2. Make a component for this shared code an import it on the other components.

What would be the ember way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a junior ember programmer myself, but in my mindset components are for stuff that's somehow GUI related (a custom tag that renders something, maybe conditionally, with supporting code added), whereas mixins are algorithmical (or, somewhat more relaxed, code that doesn't render anything for itself).

tl;dr: If you need a template, it's a component, otherwise it's a mixin.

This might be oversimplified for certain situations, but so far this has worked for me.

Comment: JFTR: Contradicting answers with examples where this falls short would be very welcome.

Comment: I don't have much experience on Ember but this makes a lot of sense to me.